# Slot problems with QT, linker error

Tags: c++, qt, slots

Was wanting to ask about a linker error I keep getting. I installed QT and am using it on Visual Studio 2005. Basically whenever i try and declare a slot I get this linker error message.

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall ipodGuiLoaderQT::hello(void)" (?hello@ipodGuiLoaderQT@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall ipodGuiLoaderQT::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@ipodGuiLoaderQT@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z) moc_ipodguiloaderqt.obj

This usually suggests that I haven't included the correct header file. But I should have. Here's my code so far.

```
#ifndef IPODGUILOADERQT_H
#define IPODGUILOADERQT_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QObject>
#include "ui_ipodguiloaderqt.h"


class ipodGuiLoaderQT : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ipodGuiLoaderQT(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~ipodGuiLoaderQT();

private:
    Ui::ipodGuiLoaderQTClass ui;

    QAction* blah;

    public slots:
        int hello();


};

#endif // IPODGUILOADERQT_H
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a linker error, so it's not a header problem. Did you implement that slot somewhere? (Make sure you try a clean build too.)

Comment: yeah supreme stupidity! Sorry for wasting time! Forgot to implement it in cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall ipodGuiLoaderQT::hello(void)"

The linker is clearly saying you that it couldn't find which is the definition of `ipodGuiLoaderQT::hello(void)`. What you have as a part of the class `ipodGuiLoaderQT` is just the declaration and check whether you have provided it's implementation (i.e., definition) in the corresponding source file and compiled it too.